# get a list of posts from Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I can get a category id or slug for my custom taxonomy just fine, but I then need to be able to get all the posts as an array for that taxonomy entry.
My code is as follows:

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

endwhile;
```

When I add 'category_name'=>'my_taxonomy_name' to the args array, it just causes the $the_query to be empty although I know that there is post in there.
I have also tried changing it to 'cat'=>22, but this also has the same fault.

Can anyone help?

Cheers
John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Taxonomy Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters).

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => '22'
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    //content
endwhile;
?>
```